# How to automatically adapt the text size in a shape with a fixed height in Visio

Tags: microsoft-visio, microsoft-visio-2013, resizing

I have created a shape (a rectangle) with fixed dimensions, **I cannot change theses dimensions**.

In this shape a text is automatically written by a vba code.  But this text is different depending on a precedent choice in a userform.

I would like to shrink this text in the shape depending on its height.

I have searched on the Internet but I have not found any solutions, working with formulas in txtHeigh or txtWidth, the size of Characters or other.

I apologize I cannot provide you any picture because it is for work with private data. You may imagine a rectangle in which I want to adapt the text size to the shape.

[image: Picture of my issue]

Answer (score 0):

Set the cell **Character** -> **Size** = **10 pt*Height/0.75 in**

You will need to change the **10 pt** and/or the **0.75 in** to adjust the ratio of text size to height that you want.

Comment: Thank you for your response but I guess it would not solve my problem, the fact is that I cannot change the size of my text in the different shapes one by one, I slide a shape on my page and then it is automatically filled by a macro. But depending on my choice the height of the text is different. I think your solution work if the change of the 10 pt and/or the 0.75 in could be automatic (but I don't know how to do that). I edit my post with a picture to show you a better vision of the issue.

Answer (score 0):

visio 2013:

1. open developer tools
2. open shapesheet from the shape
3. enter following in the cell where the size is defined:
   ROUND(Height/2.835,2)

The text is now in relation to the height of the shape.

It is also possible to create a relation to the width:
ROUND(Width/2.835,2).

Is that what you want?